# Why is the output of the type bool equal to 0 in this case?

Tags: c++, boolean

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  cout << ('x' > 0xFF) || (3 * 5 < 35) && (53 > 5 * 3);
  cout << ('x' > 0xFF);
  cout << (3 * 5 < 35) && (53 > 5 * 3);
  return 0;
}
```

I get 001 even though it should be 101 as far as I understand.

Answer (score 6):

According to [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `<<` has higher precedence than `||` and `&&`. So

```
cout << ('x' > 0xFF) || (3 * 5 < 35) && (53 > 5 * 3);
```

is actually parsed as (extra spaces added for emphasis)

```
( cout << ('x' > 0xFF) )    || (3 * 5 < 35) && (53 > 5 * 3);
```

It's printing out the result of `'x' > 0xFF` (which is false) and basically ignoring the rest. To get what you want, you need to wrap it in parentheses:

```
cout <<    ( ('x' > 0xFF) || (3 * 5 < 35) && (53 > 5 * 3) );
```

As to why `(cout << A) || B` is valid in the first place, [std::basic_ostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) (of which `cout` is an instance) has the following overloads:

1. [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) - writes the data to the stream and returns a reference to the stream (that's what lets you chain multiple calls together).
2. [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) - returns whether the stream is still valid.

So `(cout << A) || B` is syntactic sugar for `static_cast<bool>(cout.operator<<(A)) || B`